# Node.JS add children object to object using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, lodash

I have an object that looks like this:

```
[{
     "id": 3298,
     "kanji": "籲",
     "part": "一 ｜ 亅 个 ハ 冂 口 目 冊 竹 貝 頁 龠 廾",
     "createdAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:33.993Z",
     "updatedAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:33.993Z"
 }, {
     "id": 5801,
     "kanji": "龥",
     "part": "一 ｜ 亅 个 ハ 冂 口 廾 目 冊 貝 頁 龠",
     "createdAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:34.102Z",
     "updatedAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:34.102Z"
 }]
```

I would like to combine this with an array that holds unique the `kanji` and `part` and remove the duplicate part. I want it to return the result as follows

```
{
    "kanji": ["籲", "龥"],
    "part": ["一", "｜", "亅", "个", "ハ", "冂", "口", "目", "冊", "竹", "貝", "頁", "龠", "廾"]
}
```

How can I use the `lodash` to do it?

Comment: Why do you have to put the expected object on an array?

Comment: @Eddie  I just edited my expected object, thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` with `uniq` to get all unique value in an object.

```js
const data = [ { "id": 3298, "kanji": "籲", "part": "一 ｜ 亅 个 ハ 冂 口 目 冊 竹 貝 頁 龠 廾", "createdAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:33.993Z", "updatedAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:33.993Z" }, { "id": 5801, "kanji": "龥", "part": "一 ｜ 亅 个 ハ 冂 口 廾 目 冊 貝 頁 龠", "createdAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:34.102Z","updatedAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:34.102Z" } ];
const result = {
      kanji : _(data).map('kanji').uniq().value(),
      part : _(data).map('part').split(' ').uniq().value()
     };
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#flatMap) to get a flattened array for kanjis and parts. Then use uniq to only retain unique elements:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": 3298,
    "kanji": "籲",
    "part": "一 ｜ 亅 个 ハ 冂 口 目 冊 竹 貝 頁 龠 廾",
    "createdAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:33.993Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:33.993Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 5801,
    "kanji": "龥",
    "part": "一 ｜ 亅 个 ハ 冂 口 廾 目 冊 貝 頁 龠",
    "createdAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:34.102Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:34.102Z"
  }
];

const result = {
  kanji: _.uniq(_.flatMap(data, 'kanji')),
  part: _.uniq(_.flatMap(data, p => p.part.split(' ')))
};

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), you can achieve your required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const arr=[
  {
    "id": 3298,
    "kanji": "籲",
    "part": "一 ｜ 亅 个 ハ 冂 口 目 冊 竹 貝 頁 龠 廾",
    "createdAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:33.993Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:33.993Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 5801,
    "kanji": "龥",
    "part": "一 ｜ 亅 个 ハ 冂 口 廾 目 冊 貝 頁 龠",
    "createdAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:34.102Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-04-16T02:27:34.102Z"
  }
]

let result= arr.reduce((o,v)=>{
 o.kanji.push(v.kanji);
 o.part=[...o.part,...v.part.split(' ')];
 return o;
},{kanji:[],part:[]});

console.log(result);
```